# Get JQuery element By ID or Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

How can I get the element number 5 **innerHTML** of this JQUERY Object?

[image: jquery obj]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Type the text into the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
jQueryObjName.eq(4)[0].innerHTML
```

But most simply, using jQuery you can do

```
jQueryObjName.eq(4).html()
```

Moreover, it seems that element has an id so this should work too:

```
$('#getUp.OT').html()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#id") // for ids
$(".class") // for classes
```

W3Schools has everything you may think of:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Even better, you can consult the jQuery documentation which is full of selector examples:

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: `$("#class") //for class` is not correct. also it does not answer the question